# Where `io.flutter.embedding` comes from in Android project with embedded Flutter AAR module?

Tags: flutter

Can I use `io.flutter.embedding.android` dependency inside Android project without Flutter SDK installed? I embed Flutter app as an AAR package. ([AAR flutter module embedding in Android setup](https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup#option-a---depend-on-the-android-archive-aar) says "This option allows your team to build the host app without installing the Flutter SDK.".

Therefore, the answer seems to be "yes, the docs says that". But I've read somewhere that `io.flutter.embedding` comes from the Flutter SDK. How is it possible to use FlutterActivity and other niceties from `io.flutter.embedding` in Android app without Flutter SDK? Even if I have Flutter module AAR, I have to connect it to Android somehow, and that's where FlutterEngine and FlutterActivity comes in...

Is the Engine and embedding API delivered with AAR? I can't find the answer quickly.